# How to get ITypeBinding of HashMap in JDT without parsing code

Tags: java, eclipse, parsing, hashmap, eclipse-jdt

I need to get class binding ITypeBinding of Java library classes (such as HashMap) before parsing code with JDT parser.

Is it possible and how?

I expect solution that correspond to following pseudo code:

`ITypeBinding hashMapLibraryType = JDT.resolveTypeBinding(HashMap.class);`

I've looked to `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup` but it's methods require scope to work with and I don't know where to get such scopes in my case when I have no code parsed.

Comment: I don't think that is possible since there are cases where the scope matters. But `ITypeBinding` is an interface, so you can implement it yourself.

Comment: You would also require some way to say which JRE to look in (Eclipse may now about many JREs) - that is normally done from the compilation unit build path.